# subfigure inside tabular multirow

Tags: floats, multirow, subcaption

I'm trying to align 3 subfigures in a 2-by-2 table, where the second column is a multirow spanning the two rows.

Here's where I am:
[image: Three placeholders for subfigures, misaligned]

Usually `\multirow` vertically centers its contents, but that's not happening with the subfigure.

Here's the code to generate the previous image.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[subrefformat=parens,labelformat=parens]{subcaption} %% provides subfigure
\usepackage{tabularx} %% tabularx and multirow so that we can do nice subfigure layouts
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[width=1.9in, height=1.9in]{logo}
                \caption{}
            \end{center}
        \end{subfigure} & \multirow{2}{.5\textwidth}{
            \begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
                \begin{center}
                    \includegraphics[width=3.9in, height=3.9in]{logo}
                    \caption{}
                \end{center}
            \end{subfigure}
        } \\
        \cline{1-1}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[width=1.9in, height=1.9in]{logo}
                \caption{}
            \end{center}
        \end{subfigure} &  \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That-a-way? You can reference the subfigures  adding a label in the first argument of `\subcaptionbox` which is to contain the caption text and the label:
    \documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[margin=1in, showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage{caption} \usepackage[subrefformat=parens,labelformat=parens]{subcaption} %% provides subfigure
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{cleveref}
    \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

```
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering\setlength\tabcolsep{1.25em}
  \begin{tabular}{c|c}
    \subcaptionbox{\vspace*{2ex}\label{1st-fig}}{\includegraphics[width=1.9in, height=1.9in]{logo}} & %
    \multirow{2}{*}[\dimexpr1.9in-\baselineskip-0.5\abovecaptionskip-0.8ex\relax]{\subcaptionbox{label{3rd-fig}}{\includegraphics[width=3.9in, height=3.9in]{logo}}}
    \\
    \cline{1-1}
    \subcaptionbox{\label{2nd-fig}}{\includegraphics[width=1.9in, height=1.9in]{logo}}
                                                                                                    &
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Some figures}
\end{figure}
We see in \cref{1st-fig} …

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain why my approach didn't work?

Also, where can I place a `\label` so that I can reference the subfigures? I stripped that from my minimal example, but I had it after `\caption{}`

Comment: @Gus: The label has to go in the first argument of `\subcaptionbox` (see my edit). Why your approach doesn't work is hard to say. My first idea is that multirow isn't really done for that, as `multirow{2}` means the cell will use 2 `lines`, not `2` rows. So you should use the optional argument to make a manual adjustment.

Comment: I don't believe you edited the code to correspond to the new figure.

Comment: @Gus: Oh! yes. I messed up with different versions of the code. It's corrected now. Thanks for pointing it.